# Django - call original and overriden save method

Tags: python, django

This may be a noobish question but it bothers me quite a lot (I'm quite new to both django and python)

In my django app, I overrided the save() method of a model to perform some interaction on the file system.

I created a form class like this :

```
class AddItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OriginalModel
```

So, in my views, when I call form.save(), eveything works fine.

But, when testing my app, I'd like to be able to call the original save() method to avoid creating plenty of files that I won't use and have to take care of.

What I tried is to create a savebis() method, in order to preserve the original save() method, but then how can I pass it to the ModelForm, so that I can call form.save() or form.savebis()?

EDIT : savebis() is already written and working in my model. I want to be able to call it from a modelform instance, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Are you confused about how to call savebis(), or how to define it?

Comment: Well, if I define savebis() in my original model, I don't know how to pass it to the modelform so that I can call form.savebis() (I need savebis() to be callable from both the modelform and the model)

Comment: Why don't you also add savebis() to the ModelForm ? I think you could also add an optional argument to your save method.

Comment: Create/Use some property from settings.py like "TEST = True". In your save(), check this property. If TEST is True, then skip the file creation process.

Comment: @pistache I'm sorry I was not clear enough :) adding savebis() to the modelform is basically what I want to do, but how? (I don't want to write it twice, the code is already written and working in the model, I just want to add it to the modelform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it sounds to me like you've got some optional processing that should occur in the `Model`'s save method.  As suggested in the question comments, just add a `TESTING = True` type constant to your `settings.py` file used during testing and check this value in the `Model` `save` method:

```
from django.conf import settings

class OriginalModel(Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not settings.TESTING:
            # Do some file system interaction, but not during testing.
            pass
        # Now save instance as per normal.
        return super(originalModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you go down the path of overriding the `ModelForm` `save` method then you have to replicate existing functionality of the `ModelForm` `save` method, and changing it to call you model's `savebis()` method instead of the `save()` method.  I'd advise against going down this path as it make the code more complex than need be.

Comment: This gets the job done, though I thought it would be better to have the code and the testing stuff completely separated. Well, nevermind. Thanks!

Comment: @LogIn I agree, it's probably not ideal.  You need to decide somewhere that you're testing and a different code path is to be taken.  How were you proposing to implement that difference?  Via a test in the `ModelForm` code?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to have two methods at my disposal : the vanilla save(), and my custom save which I called savebis(). This way, in my code I would have used only savebis() (since only this one is useful to me), but in my tests I could have used vanilla save(). I thought Django (or python) had a way to do this easily; if it is not the case, using a TEST value in the settings is probably the best way

Comment: It is not ideal to me to have to (slightly) different code path for testing and production... IMHO, you should test exactly the code that will be run. Another approach could be to a) make the root path where filesystem stuff occurs configurable (in settings.py for example) b) configure it differently for prod. or testing c) write a "cleanup" function that can be called in the tests.

Comment: @niconoe Good suggestions, this is what I would normally do.  I use [mkdtemp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) to create a temporary directory just for the test being run, and clean up afterwards.  This is made much simpler by creating a context manager object which does the creation/deletion.